# Query to select company data

Tags: mysql

A company has different types of products (trains, motorbikes, cars ect.) From this [sample database](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sample-database.aspx):

```
ORDERDETAILS table contains Ordernumber and Productcode
PRODUCTS table contains Productcode and Productline
```

The query to list the order numbers that include **either** ships or trains is:

```
Select DISTINCT ordernumber from orderdetails
WHERE productcode IN (
 Select productcode  
  From products 
  where Productline =’ships’or productline =’train’
 );
```

How to list the Ordernumber that have **both** Productline 'Ship' and 'trains'?

This gives me an empty set:

```
Select DISTINCT ordernumber FROM orderdetails
 WHERE productcode IN (
  Select productcode  
   From products 
   where Productline =’ships’ AND productline =’train’
  );
```

Why can't I just change the "or" to "and"? What would be the correct syntax for the empty set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or, since you do not *really* want to `join` the tables, you could also do

```
Select ordernumber FROM orderdetails od
WHERE EXISTS (Select 1  From products where Productline =’ships’ AND productcode=od.productcode)
AND EXISTS (Select 1  From products where Productline ='trains’ AND productcode=od.productcode)
```

Using `EXISTS` you no longer need `DISTINCT` in the main clause.

You probably have realised by now that the simple `AND` combination in your original query can never work since a single record in your `products` table can never be of  *both* `Productline`s 'trains' *and* 'ships' at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a double `join` on the `products` table and apply the condition like

```
Select od.ordernumber 
FROM orderdetails od
join products p on od.productcode = p.productcode
join products p1 on od.productcode = p1.productcode
where p.Productline = 'ships'
and p1.productline = 'train';
```